# DJango HttpResponseRedirect not passing "request" to function

Tags: python, django

I am using the DJango login/authentication functionality. I have extended it with a Profile using the [Extending The Existing User Model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/customizing/) approach.

In the "Profile" is a variable called **restrole**. In the code below, **restrole** is being used to control the NEXT screen the user sees (as well as as the data on it):

```
def user_login(request):

if request.method == 'POST':
    # First get the username and password supplied
    username = request.POST.get('username')
    password = request.POST.get('password')

# Django's built-in authentication function:
user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)

    if user:
        # Check it the account is active
        if user.is_active:

            # Log the user in.
            login(request, user)

            myprofile = user.userprofileinfo
            restrole = myprofile.restrole

        if  restrole == 1:
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('authinduction:induct-owner'))
        elif restrole == 2:
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('authinduction:induct-office'))
        elif restrole == 3:
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('authinduction:induct-customer'))
        elif restrole == 4:
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('authinduction:induct-field-work'))
        else:
            return HttpResponse("Unrecognized Role")
```

## This Part works fine

I can get data from the "request" variable

```
# First get the username and password supplied
username = request.POST.get('username') <<< data is returned
password = request.POST.get('password') <<< data is returned
```

## The problem

When I execute one of the branches:

```
        if  restrole == 1:
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('authinduction:induct-owner'))
```

It goes to the correct function, but "request" does not appear to have any data associated with it. Getting the "username" results in getting a value of "None"

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect, HttpResponse
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from authinduction.models import Mstrauthownerrdx
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

def inductowner(request):

    username = request.POST.get('username')  <<< does NOT work, returns "None"
    user = User.objects.get(username=username) <<< causes a DoNotExist error here
```

What is the best way to come around this problem?

TIA

## Update

@Alasdair - Thanks for the response. That did the trick! I noticed that the form itself accesses the user login info as follows:

```
<input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Enter Your Logon Info">
```

As metioned above, to get the username (when doing the POST as you have noted), one does

```
username = request.POST.get('username')
```

In all of this, I keep seeing "username", but - to solve the problem, one users "request.user". Why is this the case? I ask because I would have never thought to use "request.user" to get the information. If anything, I would have used "request.username"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you return a redirect response, Django does a GET request to that URL, so the POST data is not sent to the new URL.

Since you have already logged-in the user in `user_login`, I would fetch the user from the `request` in the next view.

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

@login_required
def inductowner(request):
    user = request.user
    ...
```

The `login_required` ensures that only logged-in users can access the view, so stops anonymous users going straight to the `inductowner` view.

Comment: thanks sooooo much for the response! Can you look at the update I have? TIA

Comment: You use `request.user` because [that's the way the Django authentication system works](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/default/#authentication-in-web-requests). When you do `request.user` it gives you a `User` object, so it wouldn't make sense to use `request.username`. If you want the username, you can do `request.user.username`.

Comment: Finally, note that you may have an issue if the username and password is active but the user is not active. In that case, you don't log the user in, but you'll redirect the user to a page where login is required. It might be better to only redirect if the user is active and you have logged them in.